# Reinitializing the whole subview on the second run of app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am writing an app that creates a subview and adds it to the superview, does what it needs to do in the subview, and when I do:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

and press the button to go to the second view again, the activity is left in the finish state from the last time I was in the subview. Namely, in the subview it plays a video and when I come back the second time the video is in the finished state.

Could anyone please tell me how I could reinitialise the whole thing so it literally does the "viewDidLoad" again? Because as it seems to me, it doesn't "reload the view".

This is what I'm doing in the main view.

```
-(IBAction) localize: (id) sender{
    [self showSplash];
}
-(void) showSplash{
    UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    modalViewController.view = splash;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject: nil afterDelay:2.5];
}
-(void) hideSplash{
    [[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [[self modalViewController] release];
    [self.view addSubview:locatorView.view];
}
```

In the "locatorViewController" viewDidLoad, I'm initialising an MPMoviePlayerController, indeed and adding it as a subView of the main view's subview. Once the video is done playing, I have a button that allows the user to go back and try again - perhaps another video will show. But the MPMoviePlayerController is still on the first video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an action/method to do the addsubview call, and right before that line you can initialize your video controller.

Simply create another action/method to do the removefromsuperview call.

Either way, I believe you have to be more specific on what you are doing, probably post the code where you are creating, adding, removing, etc. Also what type of view are you trying to add. From what I assumed it is probably an MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is now black when I want to play the movie the second time. Do you know how I could solve that? I've looked everywhere but have found no solution.

Comment: Done. I just removed the MPMovieController manually by just removing the subview at index: whatever the index is.

Comment: @Sorin Cioban - Ok, so tell me where are you right now on this?